# Object properties not getting modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I got a WCF service and im using Entity Framework to communicate with the database.

Of course I cannot return my entity objects so I created WCF ones.

In this code Im getting data using EF, which comes good..but then when I use the for each statement, the usersForClient is always assigned empty. This is returning an empty list at the end, but usersList is full of users.

```
UserMethods userMethods = new UserMethods();
List<Users> usersList = userMethods.getUsersByLastName(pLastName);
List<wcfUser> usersListForClient = new List<wcfUser>();
wcfUser usersForClient = new wcfUser();

foreach (Users u in usersList)
{
    usersForClient = new wcfUser();
    usersForClient = TranslateServerUserToClientUser(u,usersForClient);
    usersListForClient.Add(usersForClient);
}

return usersListForClient;
```

This is my translate method :

```
private wcfUser TranslateServerUserToClientUser(Users serverSideUser, wcfUser clientSideUser)
{
    clientSideUser.Age = serverSideUser.Age;
    clientSideUser.Email = serverSideUser.Email;
    clientSideUser.DateJoined = serverSideUser.DateJoined;
    clientSideUser.LastName = serverSideUser.LastName;
    clientSideUser.Name = serverSideUser.Name;
    clientSideUser.UserName = serverSideUser.UserName;
    clientSideUser.IdUser = serverSideUser.IdUser;
    clientSideUser.DateLastLogin = serverSideUser.DateLastLogin;
    clientSideUser.ProfilePicture = serverSideUser.ProfilePicture;
    return clientSideUser;
}
```

Comment: Try calling your service class like it is just a regular .NET application.  If that works, then you probably have an issue with your service contract.  If you let Visual Studio generate your client side code through "Add Service Reference" you probably need to refresh it.

Comment: I tried creating a user and returning it from within my getUsersByLastName method exposed in my WCF and the user gets fine to the client..the problem is with the  usersListForClient being always empty

Comment: Why is that you can't return your entity objects?

Comment: `wcfUser` is a struct or class?

Comment: Is this your exact code? If `usersList` has items I can't see how `usersListForClient` doesn't have any items.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `ref` keyword in front of the `wcfUser clientSideUser` arg. It should look like

```
User TranslateServerUserToClientUser(Users serverSideUser, ref wcfUser clientSideUser)
```